# Basic ToString Error

Tags: java, tostring

I am currently working on a project that requires a ToString. I created a very simple method and ToString to illustrate my question. My `evaluateValue` method will perform specific calculations and set the `occupation` and `age` variables.

The issue is that my ToString will not print anything. I want the ToString to display what my method has done, but not sure why it doesn't work correctly.

Desired Output:

```
Name: Bob 
Occupation: Farmer
Age: 31
```

My Code:

```
public class ToStringExample
{
    static String occupation;
    static int age;

    private static void evaluateValue(String name)
    {   
        if(name.equals("Bob"))
        {
            occupation = "Farmer";
            age = 31;
        }

        if(name.equals("Fred"))
        {
            occupation = "Programmer";
            age = 45;
        }

        else
        {
            occupation = "Undefined";
            age = 22;
        }
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "Name: " + name + "\nOccupation: " + occupation + "\nAge: " + age;       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println(evaluateValue("Bob"));
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't pass a `void` type to another method.

Comment: **What problem are you having?**

Comment: @SLaks I can't get my variables to print from my toString.

Comment: @YoungandFree you never called toString...

Comment: Your code does not compile.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about language fundamentals which can be learned much better from a resource like the official tutorials, a book or a class. Teaching how the language works in such a broad manner is outside of Stack Overflow's scope. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't make everything `static`. Do instantiate an instance (so you can call `toString()` on it). Something like,

```
public class ToStringExample {
    String occupation;
    int age;
    String name;

    public ToStringExample(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void evaluateValue() {
        if (name.equals("Bob")) {
            occupation = "Farmer";
            age = 31;
        } else if (name.equals("Fred")) {
            occupation = "Programmer";
            age = 45;
        } else {
            occupation = "Undefined";
            age = 22;
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + name + "\nOccupation: " + occupation + "\nAge: "
                + age;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ToStringExample tse = new ToStringExample("Bob");
        tse.evaluateValue();
        System.out.println(tse);
    }
}
```

Output is

```
Name: Bob
Occupation: Farmer
Age: 31
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't print `evaluateValue()` because it is a `void` method. Instead, you could remove the `static` modifier from evaluateValue and create a `ToStringExample` object. Then you could call `evaluateValue("Bob")` and print the object.